# Keyup Element Events not refreshing or event not Removing

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind, keydown

I have a input with keydown bind event

`<input id="elementId" type="text" />`

```
$('#elementId').bind('keydown',function(){
.. do something
})
```

To remove keydown event on a condition I use this `$("#EnquiryId").off()`
but the event dont removed. when i manually inspect it then tha same code work. so do i have to refresh element event list ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the event listener on the off() method.

```
$("#EnquiryId").off('keydown');
```